# What does rm -R do?

Tags: rm

First, googling for things like "-R", is useless. All kinds of unrelated answers come out. I know what `rm -rf` does, but what does `rm -R` does? (specially `rm -R <directory>`)
(I actually found one match but is says "it is the raw eggs option" which is an enigma to understand)

Comment: -R (uppercase) is exactly the same as -r (lowercase) on any POSIX system. Was it what you were really asking about?

Comment: In many commands, the case is important to distinguish operations so I am asking for specifically the upper case R option

Comment: Not this one: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html#tag_20_111_04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The
[rm manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html)
says this :

```
   -r, -R, --recursive
          remove directories and their contents recursively
```

So, for `rm` at least, both options have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

A [`rm` command following POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html#tag_20_111_04) treats `-R` exactly as `-r`. Actually it defines `-r` as equivalent to `-R`:

> `-R`
> Remove file hierarchies. See the DESCRIPTION.
> `-r`
> Equivalent to -R.